# After upgrading raspian my crontab is gone but still running

Tags: cron, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I updated my Raspian via `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`.

Now if I run `crontab -e` I get the message: `no crontab for user123 - using an empty one`

But the jobs which I setup, are still running periodically, however I can not edit them anymore.

What can I do?

Comment: Its not a root crontab

Comment: Have a look at `sudo ls -l /var/spool/cron/crontabs` to see which crontabs have you got there.